# Gnuplot GUI for Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, gui, gnuplot

Is there a Gnuplot GUI (equivalent to wgnuplot.exe) for Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

- PlotDrop is available through Ubuntu Software Center
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jgp/- Java, so should be compatible
- http://linux.softpedia.com/downloadTag/Gnuplot+GUI others

The second two will probably have to be compiled from source, but that isn't too difficult.  The basic steps are:

- Extract the source
- Read the README (should include installation instructions)
- Find a configure script (ofter configure or configure.sh) and run it

  - Usually these create a make file
  - If there isn't a configure script, move to the next
- type `make`
- type `make install`

If you `make` doesn't work, then maybe there's a cmake file.  Try:

`cmake .`